# checking and verifying a postgres database backup file

Tags: postgresql

I've created a backup file of my whole Database but I want to make sure that the backup file is actually good 'complete'. I was trying to browse the backup file but I couldn't open it.
is there a way to verify whether this backup file is complete and will work when need to be restored ?

to make the backup I've used the following commands:

```
pg_dump -Fc my_database_name_here > database.bak # compressed binary format
pg_dump -Ft my_database_name_here > database.tar # tarball
```

and I have a Mac OS version 10.9.5

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But I think it's safe to assume that the dump is complete if `pg_dump` did not return with an error

Comment: thanks, it didn't return an error but both commands create a backup files (.bak and .tar) with exactly the same size which is 43.1 MB .. do I need to be worry ?

Comment: Internally `-Fc` is actually a tar file with a little metadata, so it's not surprising they're almost the same size. To verify a backup, restore it to a blank database on a different PostgreSQL install. Remember, you probably want to `pg_dumpall --globals-only` too, to capture users, roles, etc.